# Angular Using ng-repeat and ng-show - how to show some but not others?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to show "n" posts.  I want to independently show post.teaser or post.fullstory depending on a show/hide.  This code isn't working at all. The "best" I've done is get all posts to switch between teaser or fullStory at the same time but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it independently. Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="w-row blog-row" ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <div class="blog-block-one">
    <h3 class="post-headline">{{post.title}}</h3>
      </div
      <div class="blog-post-text"  ng-show="status" ng-bind-html="post.teaser"></div>
      <h4 data-ix="read-more" class="blog-post-more" ng-show="status" ng-click="more(post.showMore)">Read more</h4>
      <h4 data-ix="read-more" class="blog-post-more" ng-hide="status" ng-click="less(post.showMore)">Read less</h4>
      <div class="blog-text-two" ng-hide="status" ng-bind-html="post.fullStory"></div>
</div>

$scope.posts = [{title: test1, teaser: "Post 1", fullStory: "All of post 1", showMore: true}, 
{title: test2, teaser: "Post 2", fullStory: "All of post 2", showMore: true}, 
{title: test3, teaser: "Post 3", fullStory: "All of post 3", showMore: true}]

          $scope.more = function(status){
            $scope.status = !status;
            return $scope.status;
          };

          $scope.less = function(status){
            $scope.status = !status;
            return $scope.status;
          };
```

Comment: In your ng-hide/ng-show comment you put there the "status" identifier. Where does it come from anyway? You may want to include it in your object you are iterating to so you can use it as: ng-hide="post.status" or something

Comment: @amcpanaligan I think that may be part of the right step; earlier, hide and show were post.showMore but that was a dead end for me also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `showMore` to the `post` object:

```
$scope.toggleShow = function(post){
    post.showMore = !post.showMore;
};

<div class="w-row blog-row" ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-init=post.showMore = false">
  <div class="blog-block-one">
    <h3 class="post-headline">{{post.title}}</h3>
  </div
  <div class="blog-post-text"  ng-show="post.showMore" ng-bind-html="post.teaser"></div>
      <h4 data-ix="read-more" class="blog-post-more" ng-show="post.showMore" ng-click="toggleShow(post)">Read more</h4>
      <h4 data-ix="read-more" class="blog-post-more" ng-hide="post.showMore" ng-click="toggleShow(post)">Read less</h4>
      <div class="blog-text-two" ng-hide="post.showMore" ng-bind-html="post.fullStory">    
    </div>
</div>
```